# Sharepoint SPWeb rename - Exception SPException - The security validation for this page is invalid

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-api

When attempting an SPWeb rename I receive the following SPException:

```
Exception SPException - The security validation for this page is invalid.  Click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and try your operation again. - Failed to create workgroup registration entry
```

Any idea what might be the troubles here?  Here is the relevant code:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(() =>
         {
             using (SPWeb thisWeb = site.OpenWeb(webUrl))
             {  
                 thisWeb.Title = newName;
                 thisWeb.Update();
             }
          });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Set SPWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true
2) You may need to validate the FormDigest with ValidateFormDigest

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(() =>
{
    using (SPWeb thisWeb = site.OpenWeb(webUrl))
    {  
        try
        {
            thisWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

            if (!thisWeb.ValidateFormDigest())
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Form Digest not valid");

            thisWeb.Title = newName;
            thisWeb.Update();
        }
        finally
        {
            if(thisWeb != null)
                thisWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 You also should wrap this in a try/finally which sets thisWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false; at the end.